# Hibernate + DB2 trigger - SQLCODE:-746

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc, triggers, db2

I have DB2 database with some legacy triggers and I am moving from jdbc to Hibernate. My problem is, that I am stucked up with error thrown by DB2 while storing data to DB through Hibernate.

The error -746 says:

> If a table is being modified (by INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE),
>   the table can not be accessed by the lower level nesting SQL
>   statement.
>
> If any table is being accessed by a SELECT statement, no table can be
>   modified (by INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE) in any lower level
>   nesting SQL statement.

In my case I am trying to save entity (which is owned by another already entity saved in this transaction), but there is before-insert trigger in DB, which checks constraint (like "is this instance the only one that has flag set to true?"). But while the attempt to execute this trigger, error is thrown.

I already had similar error while saving another entity with another trigger and I did it like store the problematic entity by JDBC, load it by hibernate and save  the rest of entities. But this approach seems to me a bit cumbersome. Is there a way how to resolve this problem? And why exactly is this not working by Hibernate whereas by JDBC is? In both cases it is in one transaction. I tried to flush the data before storing the problematic entity, but did not help.

Comment: Which version of DB2? Is DB2_RESOLVE_CALL_CONFLICT already in use (DB2 LUW)? See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005669.html

Comment: It's DB2 v9.7 (Linux) and I tried to set DB2_RESOLVE_CALL_CONFLICT variable to YES, but it didn't help, still the same error

Comment: Did you restart the database server after setting the variable? It is one of those variables that require a restart.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the database and tried to execute insert with Hibernate but nothing changed.

Comment: It's hard to provide useful suggestions without seeing either the statements generated by Hibernate or the trigger code.